# Allow user to run a command as root

Tags: sudo

I have the following at the end of my `sudoers` file

```
nagios ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

When I try `sudo -u nagios -g nagios /usr/sbin/service syslogd status` I get

```
eval: cannot open /var/run/syslog.pid: Permission denied
syslogd is not running.
```

While `sudo service syslogd status` gives

```
syslogd is running as pid 547.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to execute the actual command with sudo and so:

```
sudo -u nagios -g nagios sudo /usr/sbin/service syslogd status
```

In the context of Nagios and nrpe, you will need to ensure that all of the commands referenced in /etc/nrpe.cfg are prefixed with sudo.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to play "wild" enter superuser mode:

`sudo su`

followed by your commands which require root permissions.

Comment: Does not really answer the OPs question of 'why invoking SUDO with -u and -g parameters' does not work.